# how to return to the same step in php fat-free framework after a redirection is made?

Tags: php, curl, redirect, fat-free-framework

I use php with fat-free framework.

I have the following scenario a client go to process.php page insert amount and currency and click submit and get redirected to a remote page of example.com to fill more details and then he redirected back to the returnurl link i provided... but i need the code to continue from the same step3 to finish the process on my website.
i use header() instead of curl_exec() because it doesn't work i tried.

page: process.php

> ```
> function call($url, $data){
> $curl = curl_init();
> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
> curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
> if ($params) {
> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
> }
> $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
> curl_close($curl);
> return $info['url'];
> }
> ```

step1:
building api url with data to post

> ```
> $url = "http://www.example.com/hosted"; $data= array(
> "amount"=>"100",
> "currency"=>"USD",
> "returnurl"=>"http://www.mywebsite.com/process");
> ```

step2:
redirecting to the link built and after finishing the process on the remote api it returns an array of data to the returnurl link posted in data.

> ```
> $link=$this->call($url,$data);
> header('Location:'.$link);
> ```

step3:
data returned from api continue to process.php from same step3...
***Client should be redirected back to here to continue the process...

> ```
> $result=explode("&",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
> $response=array();
> foreach($result as $fields){
> $field=explode("=",$fields);
> $response[$field[0]]=urldecode($field[1]);}
> switch($response['status']){
> case 'success':
> return 1;
> break;
> case 'fail:
> default:
> return 2;
> break;}
> ```

Comment: Whats the problem you faced? probably $result is empty in step3 ?

Comment: the problem is if i use cURL only, as in curl_exec($curl) it returns the data but with redirect_url field empty maybe this is why curl not working. and this is why i use header('Location:'.$url);
but if i use header() i dont know how to continue running the code from the same spot where i called $this->call()....

Comment: header function is not the same as cURL, You are redirecting user when you sending Location in header function and there is no way to go back and continue from same line where you've sent header.

Comment: i figured that header can't redirect to the same line. so how can i use cURL if redirect_url is empty?

Comment: if i use curl like so:
private function call_netpay($url, $params){
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'?'.http_build_query($params));

  $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
  var_dump($info);
    
  curl_close($curl);
    
  return $info['url'];
 }

Comment: I don't see any "redirect_url" in your codes! Anyhow cURL does not need any redirection path or url, once it gets the result it will continue running the rest of the code block (next line).

Comment: redirect_url is in curl_getinfo($curl);
*i don't have enough space here to paste the output.
["url"]=> string(464) "https://example.com/hosted/?merchantID=12345678&url_redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com%2Fnotify&url_notify=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com%2Fnotify&trans_comment=mywebsite+Payment+Page&trans_installments=1&trans_amount=55.3&trans_currency=USD&disp_paymentType=CC&disp_payFor=mywebsite+LTD.&disp_lng=en-us&disp_lngList=en-us%2Cfr-fr%2Ces-es%2Clt-lt%2Cru-ru%2Cde-de%2Czh&disp_mobile=auto&signature=XhUX6Iarhp9A7wfWyKiHBQnMyllIiWAZzklIceul0lY%3D" ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: Then correct your question please.

Comment: i don't know how to edit the question here. anyway i didnt really get a solution or a direction for this. but i suspect the problem is with the response i get in curl from the api... thanks anyway

Comment: There seems to be a lot of confusion here. I'd suggest you to ask your question on the framework [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/f3-framework) as it is the best place for debugging. Otherwise we'll end up with dozens of comments just to figure out what you're actually trying to achieve ;)